# File names validation

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I am validating many files in directory in one thread every minute.
Currently I'm using function below, which works fine. 
My questions is whether I can rewrite this method to run faster (java8?) and,   hopefully, to be shorter.

```
public boolean validateFile(String fileName) {
    fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    String[] values = fileName.split("_");
    if (values.length == 4) {
        if(!values[1].matches("0*")) {
            if(!fileName.contains(" ")) {
                if(values[3].equals("PASS") || values[3].equals("FAIL")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Rules for validation:

1. Filename cannot contain any whitespace character.
2. Filename splitter is always **_** character.
3. Values[1] cannot contains only zeros (**0**). It must have 12 digits.
4. Values[3] have to contains either "PASS" or "FAIL".
5. Array values[] length have to be always 4.

You can run and fork this code with filename examples on http://ideone.com/dh8j9M

Comment: Since your code works and you are just looking for a way to improve it, I think this question would belong better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Regular expression?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: Above code doesn't validate all the rules for file name format.  Also, scanning the text to validate file names will almost certainly be dwarfed by the time reading the directory for files in terms of clock time.  Trying to optimize this method is very unlikely to impact execution time.

Comment: @user3745362   In my case I have to check filenames, because later in the code, I am using values array extensively. In other words: in every filename, every part of the filename, means actually something, thus I have to be sure that current filename is valid.

Comment: Instead of nesting `if` statements, you can combine all conditions with `&&`. Then, replace the remaining `if(combined conditions) return true; [else] return false;` with a single `return combined conditions;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this - just a plain transformation of the branches to java-8. May be more readable, but not faster.

```
 return Optional.ofNullable("test") // your fileName
            .filter(x -> !x.contains(" "))
            .map(x -> x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf(".")))
            .map(x -> x.split("_"))
            .filter(arr -> arr.length == 4)
            .filter(arr -> !arr[1].matches("0*"))
            .filter(arr -> arr[3].equals("PASS") || arr[3].equals("FAIL"))
            .isPresent();
```

Comment: Seems like an Optional would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Even if [@Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45470776/7607923)'s answer is more **expressive**, but I think you also can break the whole `regex` into pieces to make it clearly. for example:

```
private static final String PREFIX = "\\w+";
private static final String DIGIT12 = "(?:[1-9]\\d{11}|0\\d{11})";
private static final String TIMESTAMP = "[1-9]\\d{11}";
private static final String STATUS = "(?:PASS|FAIL)";
private static final String EXTENSION = "\\p{Alpha}+";

private static final String FILENAME_REGEX =
        format("%s_%s_%s_%s\\.%s", PREFIX, DIGIT12, TIMESTAMP, STATUS, EXTENSION);

private boolean validateFile(String fileName) {
    return fileName.matches(FILENAME_REGEX);
}
```

Comment: @nanomader94 yeah, I used static imports instead, :)

Comment: BTW, I choose first answer becaues this one is not working out-of-the-box for my filenames examples and I don't have time to correct it. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: @nanomader94 It doesn't matter. Not at all. This is because your example violate the rule: "*It must have 12 digits.*", but in your example only having 11 digits. :)

Comment: You're exactly right. On ideone, last filename example, and first one valid there, have 11 digits. My bad.